# How can I allow users to enter "." in an iOS numeric keyboard with <input>?

Tags: html, ios, safari

I have read this post:

https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/

It says I can use the following code to allow users to enter numbers with a number-only virtual keyboard, which is quite convenient than the traditional virtual keyboard:

`<label for="creditcard">credit card number:</label> <input pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" name="creditcard">`

[image]

However, there is no way to enter dot here. For instance, if I want to enter `5.6` or `6.0`, I got stuck there.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you are doing well and safe from COVID-19.

```
<input type="tel" inputmode='decimal'/>
```

I’ve been using input type = tel it accepts pattern parameters and pulls up the number keyboard inputs on mobile.
The keyboard on mobile for type=”tel” has some phone-specific characters like #, but its not a bad solution until support for inputmode is better, even if it feels semantically wrong. It doesn’t seem to affect screenreaders in a negative way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

replace

`<input type="number" inputmode='numeric"/>`

by

`<input type="number" inputmode='decimal'/>`

Comment: You are answering your own question then why did you add bounty in the first place?

Comment: It's because I found the answer after adding the bounty :)

Comment: I don't know how to deal with this case (can I have my rep. back? ...)